# Why do I get ORA-00922 when trying to create this trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I want to create this trigger and I keep getting ORA-00922 error and I can't find the fix.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_briu
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employee
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET :NEW.first_name = TRIM(:NEW.first_name);
    SET :NEW.last_name = TRIM(:NEW.last_name);
    SET :NEW.id = UPPER(:NEW.id);
END employee_briu;
```

Error log:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
2/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/9       PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
3/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/9       PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
4/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/9       PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please do not spam the tags with unrelated databases (presumably to attract more readers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-356CB656-68ED-4869-8C67-FE93A78AEC9A), assignment is done using `:=` in PL/SQL. There is no `SET` command to do that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_briu
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employee
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.first_name := TRIM(:NEW.first_name);
    :NEW.last_name := TRIM(:NEW.last_name);
    :NEW.id := UPPER(:NEW.id);
END employee_briu;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I would write this as:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT TRIM(:NEW.first_name), TRIM(:NEW.last_name), UPPER(:NEW.id)
    INTO :NEW.first_name, :NEW.last_name, :NEW.id
    FROM dual;
END employee_briu;
```

Comment: What is this "FROM dual"? Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Haidrex . . . Oracle requires a `FROM` clause.  When you want to write a query that would otherwise not have one, then `dual` is used.

Comment: So I can basically call it anything right?

Comment: @Haidrex . . . No.  You need a table that is guaranteed to have exactly one row.  That table in Oracle is `dual` (that are actually other system tables that meet the requirement but this is the Oracle standard).

Comment: Any `select into` statement is going to be less efficient than a simple variable assignment though.